# Wrap specific tag outside of the RTE

Tags: typo3, rte, tsconfig

I use TYPO3 4.7 and rtehtmlarea 4.7.7

I'm currently designing a newsletter.
`<h2>` are the title of Content Element and `<h3>` are added in the RTE.

Is there a way to wrap these `<h3>` with a `<font>` tag via RTE tsconfig (or something else) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your TypoScript template (not TSConfig):

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
  externalBlocks := addToList(h3)
  externalBlocks.h3 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <font>|</font>
    callRecursive = 1
  }
}
```